# GitHub: How to download commits from a user

Tags: git, github

I need to download all the commits from a specific user, who pushed them to the master branch. The commits can be downloaded separately and automatically. Is there a way, or do I need to write a script for it?

I am thinking of writing some Java / Python script, which would download the pushes by using sha in the urls. Is there a way to specify that the script should only be downloading zips of pushes by a specific user?

Comment: what should be the zip contents? should the contents be only the modified files or the entire repo at that sha?

Comment: The entire repo at that commit. Zip will contain the files, code. Doesn't have to be zip, it's just a common way to download manually directly from GitHub.

Comment: I think I might try this script: https://github.com/mazen160/GithubCloner. If anyone has other examples, pls send them.